# Compressing PIL image without saving the file

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, image-compression

I am having trouble with compressing image in python without saving the image at the disk. The image has a save function as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10607468/how-to-reduce-the-image-file-size-using-pil). Here it optimizes the image by saving it. Is it possible to use the same procedure without saving the image. I want to do it like another python function.

image=image.quantize() [here it reduces the quality a lot ]

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: you can write the image to an in-memory `io.BytesIO` object instead of a file by passing one to `save`

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply ! This seems to be an option!

Answer (score 1):

In PIL or opencv the image is just a large matrix with values for its pixels. If you want to do something with the image(e.g. display it), the function needs to know all the pixel values, and thus needs the extracted image.

However, there is a method to keep the image compressed in memory until you really need to do something with the image. Have a look at this answer: [How can i load a image in Python, but keep it compressed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55472656/how-can-i-load-a-image-in-python-but-keep-it-compressed)

Answer (score 1):

Simple! Instead of saving the file on the file system, just save it in memory.

```
from PIL import Image
import io


def compressed_image(image: Image) -> Image:
    """
    Compresses the given image.
    :return: A compressed copy of the image
    """
    buffered = io.BytesIO()
    image.save(buffered, format="PNG", optimize=True)
    return Image.open(buffered)
```

Beware of memory limitations when using in a cloud environment!

#### Optional (only applicable to JPEG)

This shouldn't reduce the quality of the image too much. For preserving more of the quality, there are other options you can try and see the size of the output image;

```
subsampling=0, quality=100
```

Comment: Neither `subsampling` nor `quality` is applicable to PNG images.

Comment: Interesting, I'm editing the above answer, thanks. @MarkSetchell